# keeping youtube auth object based on django session

Tags: django, youtube-api, django-sessions

I need to authenticate an user on Django to allow him to post comments on a video.
I'm creating an gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService() object, setting the developer key, getting the auth URL (GenerateAuthSubURL) and UpgradeToSessionToken() after I get the token back from the user.
Then this instance ( YouTubeService() ) is allowed to do requests as this user on youtube.

The problem is that I want that to persists on the user session. How can I keep this object session-persistent?